# How to set request parameter to be avaiable within a session if the session is reset for some other reason

Tags: java, session, servlets

```
String reqParam=request.getParameter("param");

    if(reqParam!=null){
          HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
          if(session!=null){
            session.setAttribute("reqParamInSession", reqParam);
          }
    }
```

I use the code above to set a request parameter value into a session when a `doFilter` method is called. But when the user navigates to a different experience(assume a user that manages three different branches of a  shop will have separate experience for each branch) the session is cleared other than the user profile. I don't manage the module that resets the session when the user experience is changed. But I still need the parameter I set in session even if the user has changed experience.

Is there a way to associate the parameter to every request sent regrdless of the session being changed? Or any other way to handle this?

Comment: Did you consider storing values at application scope ?

Answer (score 1):

Dont' use application scope as if the session is closed for any reason the params won't be cleared. Use cookies if you can.